# Replace a space according to commas index in javascript

Tags: javascript

I got some problem in replace the space
Here is my code

```
var getTags = function(video_tagslist) 
{ 
    var commas = _.allOccurrences(video_tagslist, ',');

    if (!_.array(commas)) 
    {
        // goback?
        return;
    }

    var tagList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < commas.length; i++) 
    {

        var tag = "";
        if (i == 0) {
            tag = video_tagslist.substring(0, commas[i]);
        } else if (i < commas.length-1) {
            tag = video_tagslist.substring(commas[i-1]+1, commas[i]);
        } else {
            tag = video_tagslist.substring(commas[i]+1);
        }

        tag = _.trim(tag);
        tagList.push(tag);
    }; 

    return tagList; 
}
```

allOccurrences() is a function which can return all index of commas in video_taglist.

But when i test it, it always missing some tags inside.
For example, if i give a string ="tag5,    tag8,   tag9,   tag12,  tag7" like this. 
the result come out is ["tag5", "tag8", "tag9", "tag7"]. always missing the last but one tags. so in this situation, the tag12 was missing.

I wonder there is anything wrong in the for loop , can someone help me fixed it ?

Here is alloccurrences function

var allOccurrences = function(list, value) {
            var me = "Utils::allOccurrences";

```
        if (!utils.array(list) && !utils.string(list)) {
            log.error(me, "Given list is not an array or string");
            return null;
        }

        if (utils.string(list) && !utils.string(value)) {
            log.error(me, "Unable to search for a non string value in a string");
            return null;
        }

        if (utils.string(list) && utils.string(value) && utils.empty(value)) {
            log.warn(me, "Unable to search for an empty string in a string");
            return [];
        }

        var startIndex  = 0;
        var index       = -1;
        var indices     = [];

        var listLen     = list.length;

        while ((index = list.indexOf(value, startIndex)) > -1) {
            indices.push(index);
            startIndex = index + 1;
        }

        return indices;
    };
```

Comment: sorry, In the example, i give string = tag5,     tag8,       tag9,     tag12,   tag7.  the space was missing between each tags.

Comment: and the space replace is actually working , just always missing the last but one tags.. feel annoying now..

Comment: Can you share `allOccurrences` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the number of commas is always one less than the number of items.  Since you are looping over the count of commas, your result will always be one less than the number of items.  The logic of your if statements means that you are losing the next to last item.

you should modify your for loop to go to <= commas.length, then the middle if goes to i < commas.length, and the final else goes to tag = video_tagslist.substring(commas[i-1]+1);

```
    for (var i = 0; i <= commas.length; i++) {
        var tag = "";
        if (i == 0) {
            tag = video_tagslist.substring(0, commas[i]);
        } else if (i < commas.length) {
            tag = video_tagslist.substring(commas[i-1]+1, commas[i]);
        } else {
            tag = video_tagslist.substring(commas[i-1]+1);
        }

        tag = _.trim(tag);
        tagList.push(tag);
    };
```

This is all based on the assumption of what allOccurrences returns.

Answer (score 0):

why not use javascript split function?
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

var array = ("tag5, tag8, tag9, tag12, tag7").split(", ");

Comment: ah.. now, i have to use this way to solve, i will try this later

Answer (score 0):

is _ the underscore library?

this function seems overly complicated.  You want to convert a comma separated string of tags to an array of strings, but with whitespace trimmed?

```
var getTags = function(video_tagslist) { 
    var tagList = = video_tagslist.split(',');
    for(var i=0; i<tagList.length; i++) {
        tagList[i] = _.trim(tagList[i]);
    }
    return tagList;
}
```

Comment: no.. itś not underscore, _ is a utils i defined. and allOccurrences() is a function defined in another class